# R:Check existence of "today's" file and if it doesn't exist, download it

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to check to see if a user has an up-to-date file version of London's Covid prevalence data in their working directory and if not, download it from here:

```
fileURL <-"https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=region;areaName=London&structure=%7B%22areaType%22:%22areaType%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingSum%22:%22newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingSum%22,%22newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingRate%22:%22newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingRate%22%7D&format=csv"
```

Pasting that URL into the browser downloads the csv file. using download.file(URL, "data_.csv") creates junk. Why?

So far I have:

```
library(data.table)

#Look for COVID file starting with "data_"
destfile <- list.files(pattern = "data_") 
#Find file date
fileDate<-file.info(destfile)$ctime %>%as.Date()

   if(!file.exists(destfile) | fileDate != today()){
     res <- tryCatch(download.file(url = fileURL,
                               destfile = paste0("data_",today(),".csv"),
                               method = "auto"),
                 error=function(e) 1)
     if(res!=1) COVIDdata<-data.table::fread(destfile) #This doesn't read the file
   }
```

The function always downloads a file regardless of the date on it but it saves it an unreadable format. I've resorted to downloading the file every time as follows.

```
COVIDdata <- data.table::fread(fileURL)
```

The junk file that gets downloaded is this:

[image]

Comment: The condition in your ```if```-clause obviously yields always ```TRUE``` - I guess, the reason is, that ```fileDate``` is a vector of dates in which you seem to have always older dates. ```max(fileDate) != today()``` might work.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I think the biggest problem is why the download.file function doesn't save it as a csv file. I've attached a screenshot of what it looks like when I open it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to data.table really

Comment: @jangorecki it's a `download.file` issue, maybe the response headers aren't read correctly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this an issue with encoding the result of `download.file`, one way could be to use `fread` to get the data then write it with `fwrite`:

```r
#Look for COVID file starting with "data_"
destfile <- list.files(pattern = "data_") 
#Find file date
fileDate <- file.info(destfile)$ctime %>% as.Date()
#>[1] "2020-11-06" "2020-11-06" "2020-11-06"

if(!length(destfile) | max(fileDate) != today()){
  COVIDdata <- fread(fileURL)
  fwrite(COVIDdata, file = paste0("data_",today(),".csv"))
}
```